# UIPickerView on Separate Page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipickerview, ios5

I am working on an iPhone app. Initially, I had my pickerview in the same screen so this was just a one page app. After skinning it i realized that i want the pickerview  on it's own separate page. So i did that. However, my pickerview originally would update uilabels and other objects on that same page. How can I have my pickerview access those objects from it's new view?

```
- (IBAction)ShowPickerAction:(id)sender {
if (self.theView == nil) {
    theView = [containerView initWithNibName:@"containerView" bundle:nil];
    theView.parentView = self;
}
self.theView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:self.theView animated:YES];
```

}

That is the method I am using to call my new view. But line 3 of the above code gives me the error "No known class name for selector initWithNibName:bundle". I think that error is related to something that i did wrong in my header file. My new class is called containerView. So i did this in my header:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

containerView *theView;
```

But that gives me the error "Unknown type name containerView" even though i do have a class named containerView!!

Answer (score 0):

Look into uiappdelegate protocol or try passing values to through a static function to the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

Use a delegate to pass information back and forth to the view object that instantiatrd the picker view. You want to keep your code coupling as loose as possible, especially if you might like to drop it into your next project. Using a delegate and/or blocks are some of the best ways.